# Cassandra crashes during simultaneous reads and writes on EC2

Tags: nosql, cassandra, scalability, pycassa

We are currently using a cluster of 2 cassandra nodes on 2 larges EC2 instances. Each of them has about 65G of used data. ( Same setup for Dev and Production ).

The issue we are having is during writes on production - the CPU load becomes 40 + ( 2 core machine ) and eventually the machines become unavailable and need to be rebooted. I tried mutiple "tunning strategies" such as decreasing the total memtable space, changing ratio of eden space vs survival space in the young generation, copying larger object directly from Eden space to the Older Generation, optimizing compaction to run more frequently, using smaller # of sstables ( I noticed that during the crash disk utilization was almost none, so I tried to relieve the memory usage).

Looking at cassandra system.log, I wasn't able to see any ERRORS or WARNINGs.
Only thing that shows up during the crash is the StatusLogger output.

If I run writes on the Dev cluster, everything runs smoothly - no errors, load is max 1.5-2.
If I reboot the 2 production instances, I can run reads and writes for a while before the crash occurs, otherwise given that machines have been up for 2+ days the crash occurs within minutes.

Any suggestions, ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linking back to the first place dmn asked this: http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/cassandra-crashes-during-simultaneous-reads-and-writes-on-ec2